# How to run live share code on participant's machine?

Tags: flutter, vscode-liveshare, live-share

I want to write Flutter code on Windows and then deploy it on physical iPhone device and hot reloading the app using macOS on VMware virtual machine. I'm using VS code on both systems and I found Live Share extension as the most convenient for me. It works fine in terms of sharing workspace between two systems, but I don't know how to run Flutter code that is hosted on Windows on my macOS virtual machine.

The Live Share extension only provides shared terminal which is hosted in Windows and therefore doesnt't allow the app to be deployed on the iPhone. Also I didn't find any tools to save code from Live Share on macOS VM so it can be run locally.

If it is not possible to run the code locally, then please give another tools that are as convenient as Live Share.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but I think you might be looking for this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/tunnels or this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh

Comment: this way the code will be stored (and run) on the macOS machine, but you'll be able to edit and run it using the vs code instance on windows (and connect "remotely" to the VM)

Answer (score 0):

You could put it in a github repo and then clone onto the vm you would need to do a git pull every time though.